# ReactJS Protected Route Error: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to configure a basic ProtectedRoute in ReactJS, however, I keep receiving the following error message and I can't figure out what the problem is:

*Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of `Router.Consumer`.*

**App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import Login from "./Components/Login";
import Home from "./Components/Home";
import ProtectedRoute from "./Components/ProtectedRoute";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Login exact path="/" Component={Login} />
          <ProtectedRoute exact path="/home" Component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**ProtectedRoute.js**

```
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const isAuthenticated = true

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
      isAuthenticated === true
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to='/login' />
    )} />
  )
export default ProtectedRoute;
```

**Home.js**

```
const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div>This page is private</div>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The casing of the prop `component` is currently incorrect. The name of the prop that is passed to `ProtectedRoute` is `component` with lowercase "c". Try the following

```
<ProtectedRoute exact path="/home" component={Home} />
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Great to hear, mark the answer if resolved the issue.

Comment: Just did. It made me wait 2 minutes before I was able to. Thanks.